# Reading XML using Java

Tags: java, xml

I've looked at a few examples, but all of them seem to use simpler XML files than the one I'm trying to read.

Here's an example of the layout I'm trying to read:

```
<map>
    <map_values></map_values>

    <grid>
        <grid_values></grid_values>

        <square>
            <values></values>
        </square>

        <square>
            <values></values>
        </square>

        <square>
            <values></values>
        </square>
    </grid>

    <grid>
        <grid_values></grid_values>

        <square>
            <values></values>
        </square>

        <square>
            <values></values>
        </square>

        <square>
            <values></values>
        </square>
    </grid>
</map>
```

Currently I'm using DOM to try and read this in, but I'm not sure how to read in one grid's section of squares at a time. Right now I'm using the following:

```
NodeList squares = doc.getElementsByTagName("square");
```

but it's returning all the squares in both grids.

I'm OK switching out of DOM, I just need a suggestion for what to switch to and where to find a good tutorial.

Comment: I looked at it, and for what I'm doing JAXB might be best. I have to work on another project right now, and I'm not sure if I should mark this question as answered until I can get back to it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use JAXB for this. It is very easy to create model objects for these map.

See for example
http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/
on how to use this library.

Comment: This did the trick. I was able to create the different layers by having different classes with XmlRootElement, each one being an object inside the other.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using **JAXB (Java Architecture for XML Binding)**, as it is easy to use and also can be used to validate against XSD (if required).

**Java Beans <----> XML**

Here is a sample for giving you the feel of it:

Source: [JAXB Tutorail Basic](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JAXB/article.html)

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "book")
// If you want you can define the order in which the fields are written
// Optional
@XmlType(propOrder = { "author", "name", "publisher", "isbn" })
public class Book {

  private String name;
  private String author;
  private String publisher;
  private String isbn;

  // If you like the variable name, e.g. "name", you can easily change this
  // name for your XML-Output:
  @XmlElement(name = "title")
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
  }

  public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
  }

  public String getPublisher() {
    return publisher;
  }

  public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
    this.publisher = publisher;
  }

  public String getIsbn() {
    return isbn;
  }

  public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about you do something like this:

`NodeList grids = doc.getElementsByTagName("grid");`

And then iterate over `grids`, and for each one, invoke `getElementsByTagName("square")`?

That would solve your problem:

```
NodeList grids = doc.getElementsByTagName("grid");
for (int i=0; i < grids.getLength(); ++i) {
    Element grid = (Element) grids.item(i);
    NodeList squares = grid.getElementsByTagName("square");
    ...
}
```

Comment: I can iterate over the grids, but each item in there is a node itself, and you cant call getElementsByTagName on a node

Comment: Each item there is a `Node` instance. However, `Element` extends `Node`. You can cast `grids.item(i)` to `Element`. `Element` has a `getElementsByTagName` method.

Comment: Updated my answer, to demonstrate how.

Answer (score 1):

1) My personal preference is DOM.  SAX is usually my second choice (if performance becomes an issue).

2) There are many (many, MANY!) good tutorials on Java and XML, including:

- http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-xml-tutorials/
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/intro/
- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/intro-140052.html

3) Here's a good discussion about how to use Java and XPath to get the node(s) you're looking for:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html

Comment: The mkyong tutorial has the same problem that I mentioned above. While great for a simpler XML, it doesn't show how to overcome the issue I'm having.

Comment: That's what XPath is for! Do read the Developerworks link. And don't give up on DOM. IMHO

Answer (score 0):

You may want to find the grids first as :

```
  NodeList grids = doc.getElementsByTagName("grid");
```

Then to get the first `square` for first `grid` node, try:

```
  Node gridNode = grids.item(0);
  Node squareNode = gridNode.getChildNodes().item(2); //as it is second child node
```

****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**

But better if you may want to use some XML frameworks e.g. [**XStream**](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) which has very simple API to convert `XML` into `JAVA` objects. Using this, you may want to convert both XML files in JAVA and use JAVA comparison.

Simple steps would be:

1. Define simple Java object (POJO) e.g. `MyXMLObj` to map the XML attributes in Java attributes.
2. Convert your XMLs in Java as :

   ```
   XStream xstream = new XStream();
   //or
   XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
   //or
   //XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());

    MyXMLObj myXMLObj= (MyXMLObj)xstream.fromXML(xml1);
   ```
3. Simply Traverse your java object and get the desired attribute value as:

   ```
   myXMLObj.getGrids().get(0).getSquare();//returns square from first gird node
   ```

Comment: @Dr.Cyanide: I updated my answer with node traversal as well.